# Why adding TIMEs with CAST does not work for every row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sum

I'm using this query `SELECT *, cast(seg1 + seg2 as time) FROM tablename` but it only added the last 2 rows, why?

Every seg* column is of `TIME` type.

The last two rows were manually added in phpMyAdmin the other ones were added through Yii framework ActiveQuery.

Here's the result from PhpMyAdmin:

[image: mysql error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird things happen in MYSQL when you sum two `time` values. Namely, MySQL converts both values to numbers (by just removing the `':'` character), then sums them. Consider this example:

```
select cast('12:43:34' as time) + cast('04:09:32' as time) res
```

```
|    res |
| -----: |
| 165266 |
```

Where the result is `124334 + 40932`.

One method to do what you want is to convert the times to seconds, add them, then convert the result to a time:

```
select t.*, sec_to_time(time_to_sec(seg1) + time_to_sec(seg2)) total_time
from tablename t
```